# MANIFEST.MF issue with jhall.jar

Tags: eclipse, manifest.mf

i have created a jar-file (DicoDB.jar) with Eclipse in the folder called 'program-jar'. Inside a subdirectory 'javahelp' are the following jar-files: jhall.jar, hsviewer.jar, jh.jar and dicoDBHelp.jar (this is my jar-file which contents my help-application).
In the top directory 'program-jar' are also the following jars: jgraph.jar, gnujpdf.jar.

This is my MANIFEST.MF: (The file is manually created)

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: gui.DicoDB
Class-Path: jgraph.jar 
 gnujpdf.jar 
 javahelp/jhall.jar
 javahelp/hsviewer.jar
 javahelp/jh.jar
 javahelp/dicoDBHelp.jar 
At the end of the file is an empty line.

Now I execute the DicoDB.jar in my terminal. Everything works fine until I want to open my help-file (dicoDBHelp.jar).

I get the following exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/help/JHelp

The JHelp class is contained by jhall.jar.

Now I don't undertand why the program does not find the class.


So i hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: try to put all jars in the same line as Class-Path: .... separated by spaces.